# Button component is getting rendered twice every time

Tags: reactjs

I tried to increment the count whenever i click the button. When click the button it is getting rendered twice. But it should be render only once.

Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/async-pine-3z2ty3?file=/src/App.js

```
import { useCallback, useMemo, useState } from "react";
import Button from "./Button";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [count1, setCount1] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, [count]);

  const MyButton1 = useMemo(
    () => <Button handleClick={handleClick} title="Increment Count" />,
    [handleClick]
  );
  const MyButton2 = useMemo(
    () => (
      <Button handleClick={() => setCount1(count1 + 1)} title="Click here" />
    ),
    [count1]
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>count : {count}</div>
      {MyButton1}
      <div>count1 : {count1}</div>
      {MyButton2}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
import React from "react";

const Button = React.memo(({ handleClick, title }) => {
  console.log(title);
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{title}</button>;
});

export default Button;
```

Comment: *When click the button it is getting rendered twice* - Can you elaborate on this? You have 2 buttons included inside the the jsx and each has its own click handler and doing its function of incrementing separately. What is the expectation here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

1. Your `handleClick` function changes `count`
2. If `count` changes new `handleClick` is created
3. If `handleClick` changes you create new `<Button>`

### Solution

1. Remove redundant `useMemo`s
2. Pass a function to `setCount`
3. Remove dependency from `useCallback`

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [count1, setCount1] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>count : {count}</div>
      <Button handleClick={handleClick} title="Increment Count" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now your component will be rendered once at the beginning and never again

If you want to have two buttons, you have to have two callbacks

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [count1, setCount1] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  }, []);

  const handleClick1 = useCallback(() => {
    setCount1((count) => count + 1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>count : {count}</div>
      <Button handleClick={handleClick} title="Increment Count" />
      <div>count : {count}</div>
      <Button handleClick={handleClick1} title="Click here" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-visvesvaraya-79ku51?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<StrictMode></StrictMode>` from your index.js file

Comment: Why Strictmode have this habits?